# Jquery Animation Issue

Tags: jquery

On this page, http://bit.ly/GSFLhz, the scrolling block 'A Timeline of Successes' has an animation step of one list item when I click on left or right arrow.
If I continue to scroll right by clicking the right arrow on , the animation step increases (observed after '2007' item ). Also, now when I click on the left arrow the animation step has increased from one. How can I correct it so that the step remains one?

Thanks!

**Solution: Used the latest version of jquery and it fixed the issue**

Comment: Can provide more information on what plugin, if any, you are using for the scrolling block?

Comment: If you look at the source - you would be able to see the timeline.js file which contains the script I am using for this functionality. http://bit.ly/GSIac1

Answer (score 1):

try **console.log(cur)** inside of function, in order to check what is actual value of 'cur' variable. maybe this can help you ...

(assuming you are working with firefox or chrome)

Comment: I logged the prev and current value and it seems to be fine.

Comment: fixed it - used the latest version of jquery and it fixed the issue